# Convert XML like String to PySpark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'm using azure.storage.queue's receive_messages() function in databricks to pull messages from a azure queue. The response looks like xml but it is really just a string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
  <col1>123</col1>
  <col2>1</col2>
  <col3>Unknown</col3>
  <col4>Dog</col4>
  <col5>Owner</col5>
  <col6>-1</col6>
  <col7>Owner</col7>
  <col8></col8>
</root>
```

When I write the response to a list, it looks like:

```
'<root>\r\n  <col1>123</col1>\r\n  <col2>1</col2>\r\n  <col3>Unknown</col3>\r\n  <col4>Dog</col4>\r\n  <col5>Owner</col5>\r\n  <col6>-1</col6>\r\n  <col7>Owner</col7>\r\n  <col8></col8>\r\n</root>'
```

I know that I can split on \r\n with something like:

```
l = [x.strip().split(' ') for x in a[0].split('\r\n')]
l
```

This gives:

```
['root'],
 ['<col1>123</col1>'],
 ['<col2>1</col2>'],
 ['<col3>Unknown</col3>'],
 ['<col4>Dog</col4>'],
 ['<col5>Owner</col5>'],
 ['<col6>-1</col6>'],
 ['<col7>Owner</col7>'],
 ['<col8></col8'],
 ['</root>']]
```

I'm not sure if this is the best route and I don't want to hard code each value into the spark dataframe, because I need to iterate through all messages in the queue. Looking for a solution that converts each 'col' into a header and then grabs the value between 'tags'.

Comment: You can consider using spark sql's xpath* series of functions.

Comment: What would that look like? I found a simple answer with BeautifulSoup that I'll post below, but I'm not a super fan... it just runs.

Comment: It returns a string array of values within the nodes of xml that match the XPath expression.A simple example：```SELECT xpath('<a><b>b1</b><b>b2</b><b>b3</b><c>c1</c><c>c2</c></a>','a/b/text()');```Return：["b1","b2","b3"]

Comment: Let me try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was faster, but requires the response to always be in the same order, which mine is.

```
data=[]
for message in response:
  #print(message.content)
  root=etree.fromstring(message.content.encode('utf-16'))
  arr=[]
  for child in root:
    r=child.text
    arr.append(r)
  data.append(arr)

out_df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema = ['c','c1','c2','c3','c4',
                                  'c5','c6','c7'])
display(out_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer:

```
data=[]
    for message in response:
        #print(message.content)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(message.content, "xml")
        c=soup.find_all('col1')
        c1=soup.find_all('col2')
        c2=soup.find_all('col3')
        c3=soup.find_all('col4')
        c4=soup.find_all('col5')
        c5=soup.find_all('col6')
        c6=soup.find_all('col7')
        c7=soup.find_all('col8')
        for i in range(0,len(c)):
          rows=[c[i].get_text(),
                c1[i].get_text(),
                c2[i].get_text(),
                c3[i].get_text(),
                c4[i].get_text(),
                c5[i].get_text(),
                c6[i].get_text(),
                c7[i].get_text()]
          data.append(rows)
    #print(data)
    out_df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema = ['c','c1','c2','c3','c4',
                                      'c5','c6','c7'])
```